# Session variables seem to expire within the hour

Tags: php, google-compute-engine, e-commerce, session-variables, lamp

I hope this question finds you in the best of your spirits.

I have a website in PHP on lamp  running on a google compute engine. The session variables seem to expire within the hour.

I have tried many fixes like:

adding the below in htaccess

php_value session.gc_maxlifetime "18000"
php_value session.cache_expire "18000"

and increasing the session.cache_expire = 18000 in php.ini-production (i restarted apache after modifying the ini file)

However, none of the changes seems to work and the pain point is that if a customer keeps an order page open for more than an hour and comes back to complete it the session variables expire when they click to take it to the next page.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime says  `Note: If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.`

Comment: Thanks for replying.Except php.ini-production and .htaccess is there any other place where php_value session.gc_maxlifetime could be specified in a lamp on google compute engine? Is there any way we can figure out where all the values are specified on a lamp?

Comment: You could inspect via [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) within the script to see what is used.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood Markus' comment. You need to use `session.save_path` to set a custom directory that isn't shared between different apps.

Comment: There is only 1 app(and which is this website) running on lamp. Currently session.save_path is set to the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way of checking which file is being used could be to use the phpinfo function and then modifying the appropriate ini file to match your requirements.